# Prove that if $n>1$ then between $ n $ and $n^2$ is at least one prime.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Prove that if  postive intetger $n>1$  then between $ n $  and  $n^2$  is at least one prime.

I have known this stronger reslut:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

But my problem is constant math test,so I guess maybe there exist more simple methods? and  I want to have prove
$$\pi(n^2)-\pi(n)>1,\forall n>1$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if n>1 then between $ n $ and $n^2$ is at least one prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789789/prove-that-if-n1-then-between-n-and-n2-is-at-least-one-prime)

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?